# Firefox is breaking my small-caps

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, webfonts

I'm having an issue where `font-variant: small-caps` isn't rendering correctly in Firefox.  Any other browser is fine.  I'm stuck with this particular font, and even this particular definition of the face due to its license.

How it looks in Firefox:

[image: good dog]

How it's supposed to look (from Chrome):

[image: bad dog]

Is this a problem with the encoding of the font?  Is there a work-around?

The issue is presented in full in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakaku/rnwvpfy1/).  (Base64-encoded font was too big to put all in the question.)

Comment: Firefox doesn't support woff font do you have another backup file type to use eg ttf?

Comment: Unfortunately, the licensure for this font is incredibly restrictive, so ttf isn't an option.  Are you sure modern Firefox doesn't support woff?  That seems contrary to [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff), [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2009/10/20/mozilla-supports-web-open-font-format/), and [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/10/woff/).

Comment: Oh wow, I guess your font is broken then. perhaps take it up with the license owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is broken for those characters. Other browsers fallback to the next font in a different way from Firefox. You can see this by providing an obviously different font as the second font in the font-family. For example, in this JsFiddle, Wingdings is used as the first fallback font. i.e.

```
body { font-family: "THAT-FONT", Wingdings, "Open Sans", "open-sans", Sans-Serif; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rnwvpfy1/2/

See how Chrome displays that, showing that it's not using the "THAT-FONT" font for the broken characters.

Comment: Which characters are broken, though?  The capital letters all work fine elsewhere.  Is there a charset in the font specifically for small-caps?